# android installation problem on mobile phone

Tags: java, android, installation

My Android app in android studio is giving me an error when I try to run it on a physical device (Mobile phone) but it's working perfectly on emulator. Here is the error from the logcat when I tried to install it on a mobile phone. Note that I have tried it with another phone but still get the same error message.I was thinking that the issue is from my phone so that's why I decided to used another person's phone to test it but still got the same error. I tried it with more than two phones and more than two projects and still got the same issue

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\HP\DoctorsAppointmentApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -S 15236751' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install-create':
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:496)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3121)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1426)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:197)
at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:22687)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4938)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4848)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:240)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:151)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:166)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:656)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:494)
... 12 more''
Retry
```

Comment: "java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space" have you checked that?

Comment: please check what? phone memory space?

Comment: Yes, the free memory in the internal storage